# Call template function from std or boost thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates, boost

I have this kind of template function `template<typename samp_type> void function_name(std::vector<samp_type *> a, size_t a)` and I would like to call it from an std or boost thread and, then, detach the thread.
 For the moment, I wrote like this `std::thread t(function_name<samp_type,size_t>,(&a, b));` but I get this kind of error :

```
no matching function for call to ‘std::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>, size_t&)’**
```

How can I write it correctly?
Thanks

Comment: is the function overloaded? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Looks like a typo.  `std::thread t(function_name<samp_type,size_t>,(&a, b));` should be `std::thread t(function_name<samp_type*>, &a, b);`

Comment: `(&a,b)` is using the quirky comma operator and is basically the same as `b`, thats why the parameters dont match the function signature

Comment: If you have `template<typename samp_type> void function_name`, then `function_name<samp_type,size_t>` is invalid because the number of template arguments doesn't match.